# Как получить данные из html таблицы одной ячейки по классу из другой ячейки simple_html_dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Есть таблица на странице которую я парсю с simple_html_dom.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><div class="img ico-address"></div></td>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td>Address 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><div class="img ico-user"></div></td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>User Name</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Возможно ли получить данные из третьего столбца указав класс из первого?

Т.е указав ico-address получить значение Address 1?

Comment: Ну возьмите родителя найденного столбца и в родителе найдите третьего потомка.

Comment: Насколько помню, нет. Но вы можете получить данные по `child`  как пример,  `$html->query("table//tr[1]//td[3]").innertext` (приблизительно)